# Loss function gradiant - why the transpose?

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have a product of two matrices, defined as $Y=AB$. I need to find $\nabla_A J$ where $J(Y)$ is a scalar-valued loss function dependent on $Y$. As I understand, this gradient can be written as $\nabla_A J = \nabla_A Y \cdot B^T$. I am having some difficulty proving this to myself.

Any element in $Y$ can be written down as $y_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^M a_{ik}b_{kj}$ and it's derivative can be written as $\frac{\partial y_{ij}}{\partial a_{ik}} = b_{kj}$.

Some intense googling led me to [this](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Ejustincj/teaching/eecs442/notes/linear-backprop.html) page which uses concrete matrices to demonstrate. They use the chain rule element by element like so:

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:dLdX11-chain}
  \frac{\partial L}{x _ {1,1}} 
  = \sum _ {i=1}^N\sum _ {j=1}^M \frac{\partial L}{\partial y _ {i,j}}\frac{\partial y _ {i,j}}{\partial x _ {1,1}}
  = \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y} \cdot \frac{\partial Y}{x _ {1,1}}
\end{equation}

However, I do not know how to extend this generally to an entire matrix.

Comment: To use index notation effectively, practice the _Einstein convention_ and drop the explicit summations.

Comment: @greg got it - though the answer can be in any form as long as it extends to entire B matrix following what I wrote. I understand there other methods of doing this but I just want to see how this pans out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$There is a problem with your first derivative
$$\eqalign{
y_{ij} &= a_{ik}b_{kj} \\
\p{y_{ij}}{a_{mn}}
 &= \left(\p{a_{ik}}{a_{mn}}\right)b_{kj} \\
 &= \delta_{im}\delta_{kn}\;b_{kj} \\
 &= \delta_{im}\,b_{nj} \\
}$$
If you switch the indices to $\Big((m,n)=(i,k)\Big)$, then you obtain
$$\eqalign{
\p{y_{ij}}{a_{ik}} &= \delta_{ii}\,b_{kj} = N\,b_{kj} \\
}$$
The first rule of index notation is that *repeated* indexes indicate summation. Whenever you violate this rule you obtain invalid results. You did not intend to sum over the $i$ index on the LHS, but that is what happened.

Now let's to the whole calculation in index notation.
$$\eqalign{
\p{L}{a_{mn}}
 &= \left(\p{L}{y_{ij}}\right) \left(\p{y_{ij}}{a_{mn}}\right) \\
 &= \left(\p{L}{y_{ij}}\right) \left( \delta_{im}\,b_{nj} \right) \\
 &= \left(\p{L}{y_{mj}}\right)  b_{nj} \\
 &= \left(\p{L}{y_{mj}}\right)  b^T_{jn} \\
\p{L}{A}
 &= \left(\p{L}{Y}\right) B^T \\
}$$

---

In the above, $\delta_{im}$ denotes a [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) symbol. It has a special property under summation. It substitutes its indices onto adjacent terms in the expression.

Comment: Shouldn't the initial expression of $y_{ij}$ have a summation?

Comment: The Einstein convention reduces visual clutter. A repeated index implies summation over that index, e.g. $$a_{ik}b_{kj} \implies \sum_{k=1}^N a_{ik}b_{kj}$$ As you can see, the summation symbol doesn't add any new information, it's just boilerplate. Which is its origin story - one day Einstein just got tired of writing it over and over.

Comment: Oh, got it. I wasn't aware you were using Einstien convention. Could you also explain how $\partial y_{ij}$ becomes $\partial y_{mj}$ (Step 3 in the 2nd half of your answer)/

Comment: That's the special property of the Kronecker symbol, that I mentioned at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Thank you - one final question, how do we move from $b_{jn}^T$ to B^T? is that just cos we are doing a dot product between rows and columns and finding each element of $\frac{\partial L}{\partial A}$

Comment: Correct. Matrix multiplication in the different notations is written as $$C = AB \quad\iff\quad c_{ij} = a_{ik}b_{kj}$$ Notice that the $k$'s are adjacent to each other in index notation.